# Simple select statement as User Defined Function

Tags: t-sql, function

How would I go about converting this into a user defined function? Also, I know there are several types of UDFs... which one would be best in this case? Thank you for the help.

```
SELECT TOP 10 ParkingSpotNumber
, count(*) as 'Usage'
  FROM ParkingTransaction
  GROUP BY ParkingSpotNumber
  ORDER BY 'Usage' DESC
```

Comment: Why do you need this as a function? Not as a stored procedure?

Comment: That's how I was asked to do it - but yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are returning more than one column and you want this to be a function, then you can use a [`Table-Valued Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
create function Top_Parking_usage()
returns @ParkingCount table
(
  ParkingSpotNumber int not null,
  UsageCount int not null
)
as
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @ParkingCount(ParkingSpotNumber, UsageCount)
  SELECT TOP 10 ParkingSpotNumber
    , count(*) as 'Usage'
  FROM ParkingTransaction
  GROUP BY ParkingSpotNumber
  ORDER BY 'Usage' DESC

  RETURN
END;
GO
```

Then when you call it, you will use:

```
select *
from dbo.Top_Parking_usage()
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3233c/1)

Comment: @Clayton what is your reasoning behind accepting an answer? The other answer is identical and yet posted after this one.

Comment: You're right! I wasn't paying attention. Your solution works as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below..... it returns the table...

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_GetParkingInfo()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
  SELECT TOP 10 ParkingSpotNumber
, count(*) as 'Usage'
  FROM ParkingTransaction
  GROUP BY ParkingSpotNumber
  ORDER BY 'Usage' DESC
);


SELECT * from udf_GetParkingInfo()
```